# Error s3 put/get ops with localstack: `The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid when performing`

Tags: java, amazon-s3, testcontainers, localstack

I've recently had an error after updating testcontainers localstack version to `1.12.5` when performing s3 put or get operations. The Content-MD5 looks like is invalid.

So I found there's an issue with s3 integrity verification: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/869

So for some reason looks like there's a mismatch with the checksum data.

Error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDigest; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null)
, S3 Extended Request ID: null
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1632)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4365)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4312)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1755)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue can be fixed disabling two different properties depending what is the error by adding on the top of your class:

- For GET operations

```
    static {
        System.setProperty(SkipMd5CheckStrategy.DISABLE_GET_OBJECT_MD5_VALIDATION_PROPERTY, "true");
    }
```

- For PUT operations:

```
    static {
        System.setProperty(SkipMd5CheckStrategy.DISABLE_PUT_OBJECT_MD5_VALIDATION_PROPERTY, "true");
    }
```